# What does the sentence "The ache of empty arms was an old tale to you" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was reading a poet Sara Teasdale's poems and quotes and came across this one. I can't figure out what this line really means.

Answer (score 4):

Literary analysis is off-topic, but this is fairly straightforward:

- ache: heartache, longing
- empty arms: having no-one to hold close
- an old tale: something you have heard or experienced before, perhaps many times.

> The heartache of not having anyone to hold close is something you have experienced from of old.

Comment: Note that the verb is past tense, not present tense, so it would be better to say "was something you had experienced often"